# Flat list not showing anything even though data and render is provided

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist inside a component like so:

```
      const MyInvestments = (props) => {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
      <Text style={styles.myInvestments}>
          My Investments
      </Text>

      <FlatList
      data={props.investments}
      renderItem={renderInvestment}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

and props.investments is the following:

```
[{name:"investment1", id:"23423"},
    {name:"investment2", id: "32423"}]
```

However, the flatlist items, the investment1 and investment2 are not getting displayed on the screen whereas they are supposed to show up as items of the flatlist. How to fix this?

renderInvestment looks like the following:

```
const renderInvestment = (props) => {
  <View>
  <Text>Investment</Text>
  <Text>{props.name}</Text>
  </View>
}
```

Comment: What does `renderInvestment` look like?

Comment: added to question

Comment: Could you try renaming `renderInvestment` to `RenderInvestment` with a capital R?

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: Oh may be, you need to return the JSX? Try this: `const RenderInvestment = (props) => (
  <View>
  <Text>Investment</Text>
  <Text>{props.name}</Text>
  </View>
)`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you can try.

1. Use capitalized `const` for `RenderInvestment`
2. Return a JSX from `RenderInvestment` function like this:

```
const RenderInvestment = (props) => (
  <View>
  <Text>Investment</Text>
  <Text>{props.name}</Text>
  </View>
)
```